# Precalculus in a Nutshell, Geometry, Appendix B, Section 5, Question 14.

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, volume

A sphere is circumscribed about a cube. Find the ratio of the volume of the cube to the volume of the sphere.

So I drew this diagram:

[image]

Next, I want to relate **s** and **r**.

I apply Pythagorean theory to my diagram.

$$\left(\frac12 s\right)^2+\left(\frac12s\right)^2=r^2$$

Or more simply:

$$\frac12 s^2=r^2$$

This gives me the identity

$$s=r\times \sqrt2$$

So far so good, I think.

$$V_{\text{cube}}=s^3$$
$$V_{\text{sphere}}=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$$

Substituting for $s$,

$$V_{\text{cube}}=r^3\times2\sqrt2$$
Ratio of $V_{\text{cube}}$ to $V_{\text{sphere}}$ is:

$$r^3\times2\sqrt2/4\pi r^3/3$$
Simply:
$$\frac{6\sqrt2r^3}{4\pi r^3}=\frac{6\sqrt2}{4\pi}=\color{red}{\boxed{\displaystyle\color{black}{\frac{3\sqrt2}{2\pi}}}}$$

That's the solution I keep getting.

The answer key stays the solution is actually $\displaystyle\frac{6\sqrt2}{3\pi}$

Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Note that everything are three dimensional. In particular, you should use the "3-d" Version of Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be the centre of the **cube**, and let $C$ be one of the corners of the cube. Drop a perpendicular from $O$ to the centre $M$ of one of the faces that contains the vertex $C$.

Then $\triangle OMC$ is right-angled at $M$.

We have, in your notation, $OM=\frac{s}{2}$. Distance $OC$ is half a face diagonal of the cube. A face diagonal has length $\sqrt{2}{s}$. Half a face diagonal has therefore length $\frac{\sqrt{2} s}{2}$. 
By the Pythagorean Theorem, we have
$$(OC)^2 =\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}s}{2}\right)^2.$$

It follows that $OC$, the radius of the circle, is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}s$. The rest of the calculation is along lines you are familiar with.

**Remark:** The above argument was used because it seemed closest in spirit to your approach. To me, the following seems simpler.

Grab a cube, or something close enough. As a distant second best, draw a picture of a cube in the conventional way. Let $P$ and $Q$ be opposite each other along the long diagonal of the cube. Let $S$ be a vertex on a face that contains $P$, with $S$ diagonally across from $P$.  Then $\triangle PSQ$ is right-angled at $S$. We have $(PQ)^2=(PS)^2+(SQ)^2=2s^2+s^2=3s^2$. The long diagonal of a cuve of side $s$ has length $\sqrt{3} s$.